# Why is TransactTime not required on ExecutionReports?

Tags: fix

A couple of my brokers are not sending tag 60(TransactTime) on Canceled messages.  What is the rule of thumb for determining cancel time when tag 60 is absent from a Canceled message?

Canceled message as in 35=8 150=4.

Why is tag 60(TransactTime) not a required field on Order Canceled messages?